# What happens when you assign int to a null in C#? And good practices

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, asp.net-4.5

I'm developing in asp.net web forms 4.5.

As I am using code-first entity framework, the code for models are made by the framework. Most of them are nullable, (I guess they are the default value)

So visual studio gives me an error every time I want to operate with the integer value saying this is a nullable type.
I am pretty sure this is integer and has a value, about 99 percent of the time,
but I have no idea what would happen if a null enters.

something like this..

```
int idx = (int) item.index;
```

The best scenario would be just becomming 0, 
and the worst scenario would be showing an error and not even rendering the page.

Another thing, is this a good way to do it, or.. is it bad practice?
I don't want to set the database to not null.. because sometimes it could be null.

I guess I could do something like this...

```
if (item.skuIdx == null) idx = 0;
else idx = item.skuIdx
```

but again, I feel stupid coding about something not even would happen.
So.. what do you guys think about this?

Comment: Use this: `int idx = item.index ?? 0;` That's the perfect case for the coalescing operator.

Comment: You're going to get an exception if it's null, but you could have tried this for yourself. Instead do `item.Index.GetValueOrDefault()`

Comment: If you know it's "something that would not even happen", then I don't understand why you need to make skuIdx (and the corresponding database column) nullable.  But assuming you didn't literally mean that and it can be null, then you need to decide what the sensible behaviour is if you do happen to read a null value from the database (if your application is around for long enough, no matter what code you have now, I can guarantee sooner or later that will happen).

Comment: @Gusman Wow that is shocking. Didn't know about it. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

You just need to use a nullable type as a variable.

```
int? idx = item.index;
```

if you want to convert to non-nullable you can EDIT: NOT.
This has been corrected by the community as WRONG. Leaving it here so the comments don't look out of place.

```
int idx;
Int32.TryParse(item.index.ToString(), out idx);
```

Comment: Int32.TryParse won't work like that, anyway it's logically equivalent to idx = idem.index ?? 0.

Comment: I adjusted my answer to cast item.index ToString because... downvotes.

Comment: This is even worse, if the value is null then ToString will throw an exception...

Comment: I see, did some testing through .Net fiddle to confirm. Sorry guys, just a bit rusty. I use a few simple extension methods to do this sort of thing so I don't have to think about it much, thanks for correcting me!